# Are scala case patterns first class?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, first-class

Is it possible to pass case patterns as parameters to other functions? Something like this:

```
def foo(pattern: someMagicType) {
  x match {
    pattern => println("match")
  }
}

def bar() {
  foo(case List(a, b, c))
}
```

Comment: I played around with Scala 2.10's `Try`, before you changed your question. Maybe you still find that useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990017/threading-trys-through-for-comprehension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Kim Stebel's first answer is close to what you want. A 'pattern match as such' is no isolated entity in Scala. A match can be *defined as* a `Function1` or `PartialFunction`.

```
def foo[A, B](x: A)(pattern: PartialFunction[A, B]): Unit =
  if(pattern.isDefinedAt(x)) println("match")

def bar(list: List[String]): Unit =
  foo(list){ case List("a", "b", "c") => }
```

Test:

```
bar(Nil)
bar(List("a", "b", "c"))
```

Alternatively use composition:

```
def foo[A, B](x: A)(pattern: PartialFunction[A, B]): Unit = {
  val y = pattern andThen { _ => println("match")}
  if (y.isDefinedAt(x)) y(x)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So you want to pass a pattern matching block to another function? That can be done with `PartialFunction`s, as the following example shows:

```
def foo(f:PartialFunction[String, Int]) = {
  f("")
}

foo {
  case "" => 0
  case s => s.toInt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your magic type can be written as a structural type that has an unapply method. Depending on what kind of extractor you need, you will need different kinds of `unapply` or `unapplySeq`. Below is a simple example.

```
def foo(x:Int, Pattern: { def unapply(x:Int):Boolean }) {
  x match {
    case Pattern => println("match")
  }
}

foo(1, new { def unapply(x:Int) = x > 0 })
```

And this is how it's done for lists:

```
foo(List(1,2,3), new { def unapplySeq(x:List[Int]):Option[List[Int]] = if (x.size >= 3) Some(x) else None })

def foo(x:List[Int], Pattern: { def unapplySeq(x:List[Int]):Option[List[Int]] }) {
  x match {
    case Pattern(a,b,c) => println("match: " + a + b + c)
  }
}
```

Comment: The ```foo(1,...``` bit doesn't work in the REPL (I use 2.9.2). It led me to this interesting discussion: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/10730

Comment: Actually, nor does it work compiled. Which version of Scala did you use, @Kim?