# Threading `Try`s through for-comprehension

Tags: validation, scala, pattern-matching, scala-2.10, for-comprehension

Triggered by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5cbd16fb-14e0-4870-aae7-b140601b1e3e/view-source) (which has been subsequently edited away though), I wanted to try out how easy it would be to chain calls to Scala 2.10's `Try` construct (cf. [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/u/heathermiller/p/futures-and-promises-in-scala-2-dot-10)), using for-comprehensions.

The idea is to have a list of tokens and match them against a sequence of patterns, then return the first error or the successfully matched pattern. I arrived at the following pretty awkward version, and I wonder if this can be made simpler and nicer:

```
import util.Try

trait Token
case class Ident  (s: String) extends Token
case class Keyword(s: String) extends Token
case class Punct  (s: String) extends Token
case object NoToken extends Token
case class FunctionDef(id: Ident)

case class Expect[A](expectation: String)(pattern: PartialFunction[Token, A]) {
  def unapply(tup: (Try[_], Token)) = Some(tup._1.map { _ => 
     pattern.lift(tup._2).getOrElse(throw new Exception(expectation))
  })
}
```

Now construct the expectations for `Keyword("void") :: Ident(id) :: Punct("(") :: Punct(")") :: tail`

```
val hasVoid   = Expect("function def starts with void") { case Keyword("void") => }
val hasIdent  = Expect("expected name of the function") { case id: Ident       => id }
val hasOpen   = Expect("expected opening parenthesis" ) { case Punct("(")      => }
val hasClosed = Expect("expected closing parenthesis" ) { case Punct(")")      => }
```

Construct a full test case:

```
def test(tokens: List[Token]) = {
  val iter = tokens.iterator
  def next(p: Try[_]) = Some(p -> (if (iter.hasNext) iter.next else NoToken))
  def first() = next(Try())

  val sq = for {
    hasVoid  (vd) <- first()
    hasIdent (id) <- next(vd)
    hasOpen  (op) <- next(id)
    hasClosed(cl) <- next(op)
  } yield cl.flatMap(_ => id).map(FunctionDef(_))

  sq.head
}
```

The following verifies the test mehod:

```
// the following fail with successive errors
test(Nil)
test(Keyword("hallo") :: Nil)
test(Keyword("void" ) :: Nil)
test(Keyword("void" ) :: Ident("name") :: Nil)
test(Keyword("void" ) :: Ident("name") :: Punct("(") :: Nil)
// this completes
test(Keyword("void" ) :: Ident("name") :: Punct("(") :: Punct(")") :: Nil)
```

Now especially the additional `flatMap` and `map` in `yield` seems horrible, as well as the need to call `head` on the result of the for comprehension.

Any ideas? Is `Try` very badly suited for for comprehensions? Shouldn't either `Either` or `Try` be "fixed" to allow for this type of threading (e.g. allow `Try` as a direct result type of `unapply`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick seems to be to *not* create `Try` instances in the *inner* structure, but instead let that throw exceptions and construct one *outer* `Try`.

First, let's get rid of the `Try[Unit]`'s:

```
case class Expect(expectation: String)(pattern: PartialFunction[Token, Unit]) {
  def unapply(token: Token) = 
    pattern.isDefinedAt(token) || (throw new Exception(expectation))
}

case class Extract[A](expectation: String)(pattern: PartialFunction[Token, A]) {
  def unapply(token: Token) = Some(
    pattern.lift(token).getOrElse(throw new Exception(expectation))
  )
}
```

Then the checks become:

```
val hasVoid   = Expect ("function def starts with void") { case Keyword("void") => }
val getIdent  = Extract("expected name of the function") { case id: Ident       => id }
val hasOpen   = Expect ("expected opening parenthesis" ) { case Punct("(")      => }
val hasClosed = Expect ("expected closing parenthesis" ) { case Punct(")")      => }
```

And the test method:

```
def test(tokens: List[Token]) = Try {
  val iter = tokens.iterator
  def next() = Some(if (iter.hasNext) iter.next else NoToken)

  (for {
    hasVoid()    <- next()
    getIdent(id) <- next()
    hasOpen()    <- next()
    hasClosed()  <- next()
  } yield FunctionDef(id)).head  // can we get rid of the `head`?
}
```

Comment: So your solution to threading Trys through for is to not do it at all and do it with traditional exceptions, and catch and wrap them outside in a Try. I don't disagree the code looks good, but I am a bit disappointed and somehow this does not feel right.